# Twitter (python-twitter) package is failing

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, python-twitter

I have installed Python 2.7 and trying to use Twitter package. I have installed the 3 pre-requisite packages successfully... I have got the consumer keys and access tokens...But somehow getting this error:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                  access_token_key='access_token',
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')

 >>> print api.VerifyCredentials()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
print api.VerifyCredentials()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter.py", line 4257, in VerifyCredentials
json = self._FetchUrl(url, no_cache=True)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter.py", line 4611, in _FetchUrl
response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)
File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

All the other commands are also resulting in the same error...
e.g.

> > > statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(user)

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

First, are you connected to the internet? From the terminal you can try:

```
ping www.google.com
```

Second, are you replacing the 'consumer_key' with the actual value, i.e. '1234ABCD'?

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='ABCD1234', consumer_secret='1234ABCD', access_token_key='DCBA4321', access_token_secret='4321DCBA')
```

Also note that the value you pass has to be a string, so with quotes around it.
And also that for multiple lines in python you have a backslash after each incomplete line:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='ABCD1234', \
              consumer_secret='1234ABCD', \
              access_token_key='DCBA4321', \
              access_token_secret='4321DCBA')
```